# How to return a column of the record deleted when deleting a record in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm working on reducing managed stored procedures and have come across this not knowing how (or if) it can be successfully ported to Entity Framework:

```
-- select out filename so the caller can delete the file from the filesystem
SELECT  SystemFileName
FROM    File
WHERE   FileId = @fileId

-- now delete
DELETE
FROM    File
WHERE   FileId = @fileId
```

Basically, the proc takes an id, returns the file name of the record it will be deleting and then deletes the row.  The calling code then has the file name to perform any file system clear up reducing the potential for orphan files.

Now using Entity Framwork, I could just find all the file and perform the delete but if I was doing this in a loop, it would be terribly inefficient.

I could try to document my attempts but it's more pseudocode than anything that will compile.

Comment: You also want to avoid executing raw sql commands as I understand?

Comment: Select all the File objects from EF DbSet<File> that you want to delete and store in a List<File>. loop through the list and remove each one or i think there is a `RemoveRange` method. SaveChanges on your DbContext and then you can loop through your List and delete the files

Comment: @Evk probably, if I couldn't see a sensible alternative to the proc, I may as well just keep the proc.

Comment: And why you do that in a loop and not delete with single query? Do you care about perfomance of this operation?

Comment: This sounds like it would make a fun project to extend EF to allow using the [OUTPUT Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) for certain operations.

Comment: Yes, output clause and dynamic delete statement is the way to go here if perfomance is needed. If perfomance is irrelevant- any approach will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Select all the File objects from EF DbSet<File> that you want to delete and store in a List<File>.
var toDelete = context.Files.Where(predicate).ToList();
//loop through the list and remove each one or i think there is a RemoveRange method. 
var deleted = context.Files.RemoveRage(toDelete);
//SaveChanges on your DbContext 
if(context.SaveChanges() == toDelete.Count) {
    //and then you can loop through your List and delete the files from system
    deleted.ToList().ForEach(file => {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.SystemFileName);
        if(fileInfo.Exists) {
            fileInfo.Delete();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hypothetically speaking, if each file row contained lots of columns would that mean returning the entire row in order to pass as the predicate to RemoveRange?

Comment: Yes, that would  mean returning the entire row in order to pass as the arguments to `RemoveRange`. In EF you remove the whole object so at some point its going to retrieve the entity.

Comment: So I've taken this approach, I'm not entirely happy you require the whole row but I'll take the simplicity of it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have less than 4000 records to delete why not

1) Select the ID and File Name you want to delete
2) Store these results in an array / list
3) Delete all records using the IN clause

```
// get all of the records to be deleted
var records = context.Files.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("delete-me")).Select(x => new {x.Id, x.Name}).ToList();

// mark all of our files to be deleted
context.Files.RemoveAll(x => records.Contains(x.Id)); // not sure if this line is correct as I am writing this in notepad, but it will give you a good enough idea

// execute our save, which will delete our records
context.Save();

// return the list of records that have been deleted back to the caller
return records;
```

Comment: Is 4000 a (sane?) arbitrary amount or is there a technical reason I would want to consider another method if there were more records?

Comment: Phil, 4000 is the maximum number of operators an IN statement can handle in SQL Server. If you're doing more than 4000 then you'll need to have some kind of batch mechanism

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, if not only for me but anyone else that stumbles across this.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I would consider this a bulk operation and not a great candidate for EF (or other ORMs for that matter).  I'm not sure which is more important to you, simplifying the query, or using EF. But if you want to simplify the query, you can execute something like this and read the affected deleted values at the same time

```
DELETE
OUTPUT deleted.SystemFileName -- or OUTPUT deleted.*
FROM    File
WHERE   FileId = @fileId
```